# Copy csv file to sql table with selected columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such a csv

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results output
cat data/supervisor_salaries.csv
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
town,supervisor,salary
Anytown,Jones,27000
Bumblyburg,Baker,24999
Moetown,Smith,32100
Bigville,Kao,31500
New Brillig,Carroll,72690
```

Tried to write it to a table

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dbuser org  :dbpassword 1618 :database analysis
\copy supervisor_salaries (town, supervisor, salary) FROM 'data/supervisor_salaries.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
#+end_src
```

but it report error:

```
psql:/tmp/babel-PSl3Td/sql-in-rlHtPW:1: ERROR:  missing data for column "supervisor"
CONTEXT:  COPY supervisor_salaries, line 1: "town,supervisor,salary"
```

error "missing data for column 'supervisor', but the csv file do have the supervisor column, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\copy` command is a feature specific for Postgres terminal tool `psql`, it is not an SQL statement. All `psql` commands (started with `\`) have to fit in a single line, so you have executed

```
\copy supervisor_salaries (town, supervisor, salary) FROM 'data/supervisor_salaries.csv'
```

that raises an error because the file format was wrongly defined (default is `text`).